# Relacionamento de produtos nos models e banco

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, modelagem, active-record, abstração

Vou tentar ser breve na minha dúvida.

Como posso modelar um esquema de classes que me supram em alguns quesitos:
Isso tudo vou fazer no rails 4.1, usando o ActiveRecord como ORM atuando no MySQL.

Vou ter uma entidade `Person` que terá uma referência (objeto), para meu model de `Product`, ou seja nenhum ou muitos produtos, o caso é que este será o repositório da empresa, ou seja, todos os clientes terão um cadastro único que quando logado, verifique os produtos disponíveis para esse usuário, o que casa com vários produtos com diferentes propriedades relativas à um produto.

Como por exemplo :

Produto A terá os atributos:

- cor
- tamanho
- peso

Produto B terá os atributos:

- tempo_restante
- numero_serie

A dúvida é essa como que posso modelar essa abstração de dados?

Já estive pensando, que a cada novo produto que desenvolvermos teríamos que criar uma nova classe e adicionar à esse projeto?

resumindo novamente...

Como criar uma relacionamento de entidades em que cada produto terá os seus próprios atributos? e que um usuário poderá ter vários produtos?

É tudo a mesma dúvida, se não fui claro por favor me peçam que eu edito a questão! muito obrigado desde já!

Comment: O que você quer é uma relação *[many-to-many](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_para_M)*? Ou seja: os produtos serão compartilhados entre usuários ou cada produto será pertencente a apenar *um* usuário?

Comment: A segunda opção, um usuário poderá ter vários produtos, só que esses produtos não terão um padrão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que uma possível solução seria criar uma tabela de atributos do produto.

```
Pessoas
-id
-nome

Produtos
-id
-pessoa_id
-nome

Atributos
-id
-produto_id
-nome
-valor
```

Onde o nome é atributo pode ser, por exemplo, **cor** e o valor **branco**.

Comment: Valeu por responder, isso tem algum nome em específico ? Como eu disse anteriormente estarei usando rails, junto com o ActiveRecord, gostaria de procurar mais a respeito de como trabalhar com isso lá! :D

Comment: Se optar por esta solução, você apenas vai criar três modelos com relações 1-para-muitos (ou 1-N). Leia sobre os tipos de relacionamentos que o Rails suporta aqui: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Show de bola, vou testar com certeza! valeuu! :D